Clarification - Token Minting, Locking and Vesting Before Launchpad
I have token wallet ready to mint fixed supply, and some of token must be vested at TGE. How to manage this has we don't know yet when the approval of launchpad we about to apply will be issued. The main reason we plan to do pre-sale.

You can use the following tools to do lockups

https://lock.jup.ag/
https://streamflow.finance/

You can use Helio to do a presale

https://www.hel.io/

